# How to login into Freebase using Java

Tags: java, freebase

I am developing a Java Application. I want to log in to the Freebase account using Java. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the methods listed on this [web page](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Authentication)

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case ? Thew new Freebase APIs do not currently allow writing to Freebase.

You can get data from Freebase without logging in, you just need an API key.

Instructions are here:
http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/API